# R and ImageJ sync issues

Tags: r, imagej, imagej-macro

I have a script in R (written by someone else) which calls ImageJ for image analysis using shell() with '-batch' switch:

```
shell("C:\\ImageJ\\imagej.exe -batch [args]")
```

The analysis indeed begins, but it seems that R continues to perform the next lines before the analysis is done, and therefore tries to access some files before they are created.

If I run it with a debugger break point,and wait until it's done before I continue, everything works fine. But if I try to run it as a whole, I get an error resulting from reading an empty folder.

The shell() command has an optional argument 'wait' with a default value "TRUE", but I guess that launching ImageJ, and not its completion, is  considered as "finish" for shell and that's why R continues. 
So what can I do to force R to wait until ImageJ is done? I know I can check the number of created files in a while loop, so it will practically hold until all the files are created. But I rather have a more elegant and less dangerous solution. 
Thanks!

Comment: It would be a good idea to post the code you have

Comment: This is a great question, but you might want to include some code as well.

Comment: The code is long and complicated... I added the line of shell() command in the question. The problem is (in mu opinion) more generic: IJ works in background so R doesn't wait. How can I change this?

Comment: You could use the `readline()` function and continue after the batch analysis is finished.

Comment: But that will involve the user... and it shouldn't

Comment: There is a `Sys.sleep()` function if you need to suspend R execution while waiting for an external process to complete.